# Expresso Store orders suddenly not getting past checkout 3 to Paypal

Tags: expresso-store, paypal-express-checkout

A website belonging to a client of mine suddenly stopped working. She assures me no changes have been made. It's been 5 days since her last successful online order, and she usually gets several per week. Someone trying to order alerted her to the problem. We have both tried buying something through the site, and neither of us can get past Checkout step 3, where you click place order and go to Paypal. I checked the Paypal API credentials (we're using Paypal express as the gateway), and they are correct. I removed the inline errors and it's still spinning and spinning until it times out, without giving any clue as to what's wrong. The page finally shows a Gateway Time-Out. The website has been working successfully for a couple of years. We are running Store 1.6.3 and EE v2.5.5.

Comment: Are there any new errors in the developer console when you view your page? I have seen similar issues before when the host has migrated servers and not alerted the client.

Comment: Not really sure what I should be looking for, Justin. Nothing seems to jump out at me on that page. If the host has migrated the server, what's the solution to getting it to work again?

Comment: You would need to look in the console for items serving up with 404 or similar errors such as your themes folder which might cause Store not to function properly. If the host did move servers you would need to adjust your paths/urls accordingly. You can use something like FocusLab's MasterConfig or you can use a tool like DeployEE Helper to search the DB and adjust the paths accordingly

Comment: I'm not detecting any errors. I checked the paths are all okay. It's just not getting to PayPal. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you have inline error handling turned on in your last checkout template remove that from the opening checkout tag, save the template, clear cache and empty your cart. Then try again. Usually if you are not getting any errors and the page just refreshes it is a result of a field error in your template

Comment: It sounds to me like a server issue. At a guess I would say your host is blocking outbound connections. Are other remote services like the EE version check and Devot:ee monitor still working on the server?

Comment: Adrian - Devot:ee monitor works just fine, though I didn't have it installed previously, so if I was testing looking for a change in behaviour, that wouldn't apply. It is working now, but I just installed it. Justin - Did as you suggested. No errors, and the page times out eventually. The code hadn't been changed so I don't know why it would suddenly stop working, or what field error I might have. What can I do next?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was with the web host, 1&1. They didn't want to disclose what they did to cause or fix the problem, but it is now sorted.