# Expresso Store orders not getting past checkout 3 to Paypal for only SOME users

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

I've had this problem once before, on a website using Store on 1&1, where the checkout didn't redirect to PayPal, but got hung up on the final step and just refreshed the page (see original question/answers here: [Expresso Store orders suddenly not getting past checkout 3 to Paypal](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12875/expresso-store-orders-suddenly-not-getting-past-checkout-3-to-paypal)). The problem was sorted after contacting the host, but they didn't tell me what they did to solve the problem.

I have another website, which is hosted on Clook, and for only some users, Store is getting hung up on Checkout 3 and not going to PayPal. The page just reloads. I can't replicate the problem, and neither can my client, but he's getting several complaints from people who can't buy on the site. I am not getting any errors on the page. ExpressionEngine v2.5.5 Store v1.6.3

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using PayPal Express or the old PayPal standard? If the page just reloads when you try to submit an order, I would assume it is a validation error. Do you have any required fields on the checkout? Is it possible some customers haven't entered an email address?

Comment: Hi Adrian! I use PayPal Express. That final page is just an order review, so there's no entering of information. All the user does is click 'Place Order' and it's supposed to go to PayPal. It does most of the time, but not for all users.

Comment: The intermittent issues are always the hardest to pinpoint. Although the final page is just an order review it may be that the user has forgotten to enter their email address or some other required information on the previous step(s). Try to run through an order without this and see if you're able to recreate the issue.

Comment: Ian, I think you're right! I tried the checkout without an email address, and I was finally able to replicate the problem. I had an error in the way I was handling the inline errors for the email address, so the checkout was moving forward without it. It's now sorted, I think. Fingers crossed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments: It sounds like a missing email address was the source of the problem.

`order_email` is always a required field in Store to submit orders. Therefore, if you ask for customers to enter `order_email` on a different page of the checkout, you should always make it required there (by specifying `require="order_email" in the checkout tag)`. Otherwise there will be a validation error when they finally try to "submit" the order.

In general, if the checkout is refreshing without anything happening, it is usually a validation error. The first step is to remove `error_handling="inline"` from your checkout tag to see if there are any errors not being displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This happened on another site as well recently. The problem was in Firefox only, no other browsers. Using Adrian's suggestion of removing the error handling inline I was able to narrow the problem down to a shipping rule the client had created incorrectly. The other browsers were able to ignore it and go to PayPal, but Firefox would get stuck and just reload the order review page (checkout3). Once I sorted the shipping rule, the problem disappeared.